# How to get total price of the product in listview and Display in a textview of cart?

Tags: java, android, listview

How I can get total price of the product in listview and Display in a textview of cart and decrease the price at the product has been deleted code is given below:

```
public class ShoppingListAdapter extends  BaseAdapter{

public static ArrayList<Product> list;
public static int position;
String idValues="";
Context context;
public static Integer total;
ViewHolder holder;
public ShoppingListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Product> list) {
    super();
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    position=list.size();
    return list.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView item_price;
    TextView txt_thickness;
    TextView txt_quantity;
    Button remove;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_product_list, null);
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        holder.item_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
        holder.txt_thickness = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_thickness);
        holder.txt_quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_quantity);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.txtName.setText(list.get(position).name);
    holder.item_price.setText("Rs "+list.get(position).price);
    holder.txt_thickness.setText("THICKNESS - "+list.get(position).thickness);
    holder.txt_quantity.setText(list.get(position).quantity);
    holder.remove= (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_remove);
    for(int i=0;i<position;i++) {
        total = Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).price) * Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).quantity);
    }
    holder.remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

              final String id=list.get(position).id;

            StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    "http://arshinfosystems.co.in/demo/AoneRubber/deletecart.php",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("id", id);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(50000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
            Add_to_cart.values.remove(list.get(position));
            Add_to_cart.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getTotalPrice(){
   int totalPrice = 0;
   foreach(Product product:list){
     totalPrice+ = (Integer.parseInt(prodcut.price) * Integer.parseInt(product.quantity))
   }
   return totalPrice;
}
```

Use this price as a total price.

Comment: add this function in your adaptor and use this function when you are updating quantity, delete product.

Comment: put this funcation in your adapter class and make interface to update total value in your textview

Comment: Done but it is not happening

Comment: because of on your remove code you are not removing product in list array

Comment: Add_to_cart.values.remove(list.get(position));

In this value is a list array

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

In Main Activity:

```
        public void calculatePrice(ArrayList<Product> list)
        {
             float total=0;

            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
            {
                sub_total=sub_total+(Float.parseFloat(list_cart.get(i).price()*Float.parseFloat(list_cart.get(i).quantity());
            }

             TextView tv_total_amount=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_total_amount);

              tv_total_amount.setText(sub_total+"");
        }

        /*Call calculatePrice fuction after adapter set*/
        public void setAapter()
        {
            ShoppingListAdapter  mAdapter=new ShoppingListAdapter (context,list);
            listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            calculatePrice(list);
        }
```

In Adapter: Call calculatePrice function after removing product

```
        holder.remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*After call webservice remove product from list*/
                list.remove(position)
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                if (context instanceof MainActivity) {
                    ((MainActivity) context).calculatePrice(list);
                 }
            }
        });
```